# Python - How to write recursively without global var

Tags: python, recursion

I am working on a recursive function to write subcategories of a tree. I don't want to use a global var, what is the best way to write to the file on the recurse method?

```
def recurse(i):
    Xmlfile = file("index.html", "w")
    if i < 5:
        Xmlfile.write(str(i))
        recurse(i+1)
    return(None)

def main():
    Xmlfile = file("index.html", "w")
    Xmlfile.write("I")
    recurse(3)
    Xmlfile.write("O")
```

The expected output should be something along the lines of: I 3 4 5 O, but I am only getting I O.

Comment: Pass file handle as parameter to the recursion function.

Comment: where `n` comes from?

Comment: @LittleQ Nice eye, I changed it for I

Comment: making `recurse()` function irrecursive is better

Comment: @LittleQ Original code is something like: Get children with ParentID i, for child in children: Get UniqueId, Get children with UniqueID and Repeat. I had to made it simpler before posting it into stack

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pass it as an argument. The way you're doing it will reopen and truncate the file on every iteration.

```
def recurse(f, i):
    if i < 5:
        f.write(str(i))
        recurse(f, i+1)

def main():
    with open("index.html", "w") as xmlfile:
        xmlfile.write("I")
        recurse(xmlfile, 3)
        xmlfile.write("O")
```

Note that I've replaced `file()` with the recommended `open()`, and have added a context manager to ensure the file gets closed.

Comment: Just to add a link to the documentation concerning the usage of [`file`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#file): "When opening a file, it’s preferable to use [`open()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open) instead of invoking this constructor directly."

Answer (score 1):

Try passing the file to the function. When you create the file in the function, it creates a new file every time you call the function. It'll work if you change it to something like this:

```
n=6

def recurse(i, Xmlfile):
    if i < n:
        Xmlfile.write(str(i))
        recurse(i+1, Xmlfile)
    return(None)

def main():
    Xmlfile = file("index.html", "w")
    Xmlfile.write("I")
    recurse(3, Xmlfile)
    Xmlfile.write("O")
```

Comment: I saw your answer after posting mine. But yeah, no new information.

Answer (score 0):

As stated by both [TigerhawkT3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40277460/7067541) and [Manali](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40277602/7067541), you should pass `Xmlfile` to the function.

---

Changing it a little more:

```
def recurse(i, Xmlfile, deepness = 0, times = -1):
    if times == -1:
        times = i
    if deepness < times:
        Xmlfile.write(str(i))
        recurse(i+1, Xmlfile, deepness+1, times)

def main():
    Xmlfile = file("index.html", "w")
    Xmlfile.write("I")
    recurse(3, Xmlfile)
    Xmlfile.write("O")
```

Both `deepness` and `times` work together to remove the need of a static *number of repetitions* (as in `i < 5`). Now you can recurse as many times as you want as in *recurse(**n**, Xmlfile)*.